# asp.net textEdit losses focus after typing one or two characters

Tags: asp.net, focus, autofocus, textedit

I have a textEdit that is lossing focus after typing a couple characters. There is nothing special about the textEdit, I have several on the page and the others work just fine.

```
<TextEdit Placeholder="Enter First Name" @bind-Text="PersonModel.FirstName">
    <Feedback>
    <ValidationNone>Please enter First Name</ValidationNone>
    <ValidationError>First Name is required.</ValidationError>
    </Feedback>
</TextEdit>
```

I played around with autofocus and that didn't help. I am really at a loss of what to do.